# django allauth add custom user information on top of social accounts based on view

Tags: django, django-allauth

I want to be able to flip a boolean in the user model depending on which sign up form the user signed up from on my site.  For example, I have two forms (regular user and super user sign up form).  IsSuper is a boolean variable that decides whether a user is a regular user or super user, defaults to false.  On the Super user sign up form, i have a hidden checkbox that sets the variable to IsSuper to true.

This works fine except when someone signs up through a social account, the variable IsSuper will always use the default value regardless of which form the user signs up from.  Any solutions for this?

Comment: quote "i have a hidden checkbox that sets the variable to IsSuper to true" - that's a terrible idea! Without seeing your code I would suggest that you do this on your view.

Comment: I've considered doing it in the view instead but to me, a view should just be a view and shouldn't be a place where I set values.  I figured I might as well keep the data where every other data is.  Why do you think it is better in the view?

Comment: I can see it being a bad idea if super had an additional cost compared to regular users.  In my case, all users are eligible for either regular or super users at the same cost.